# html anchor tag redirection with a string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, anchor

I have an anchor tag for redirecting from one page(for example: page2.aspx to page1.aspx) to another.

```
   <ul <li><a href="Page1.aspx">Get Information</a></li></ul>
```

Now, when redirected to page1.aspx , I need to load a particular Tab(or any component) by checking that the string value(to be sent while redirecting with my anchor tag) page2.aspx.

In Ready function of page1 , I need to do Something like this:

```
If redirected from page2.aspx based on some condition 

// load these components //
```

To achieve this, I think....  I need to pass some string value or query string kinda parameter in my anchor tag.

Please suggest how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Using client side or server side..?

Comment: There is no `Ready` function on client-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got This :

```
 <ul <li><a href="Page1.aspx?Value="Approved">Get Information</a></li></ul>

 $(document).ready(function () {

// Get Query String Value 
 var qrStr = window.location.search;
        if (qrStr != null && typeof qrStr != 'undefined') {
            qrStr = qrStr.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
            //alert(qrStr);
            if (qrStr == "Approved") {
               // Perform required tasks
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using GET url parameters.

try:

```
<a href="Page1.aspx?ref=menu">Get Information</a>
```

now, in the `Page1.aspx`, within the `Page_Load` method (assuming you're using ASP.NET Forms and not MVC):

```
if (!String.isNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString['ref']) && Request.QueryString['ref'] == 'menu') 
{
    // do something
}
```

that's the main idea.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I need to do it using Client-Side

Answer (score 0):

Pass `query string` like this

```
<ul <li><a href="Page1.aspx?UserId="+txtUserId.Text">Get Information</a></li></ul>
```

and retrieve the query string as

```
lblUserId.Text = Request.QueryString["UserId"];
```

**Or**

you can check the `referrer` page using jquery

```
if referrer page is this do something
else do something
```

to get referrer page use this.

```
var referrer =  document.referrer;
```

Comment: I need to use client - side only.

Comment: There is no page load, textbox, label etc. I just need to pass a string value "APPROVED" in anchor click. and in document.ready of the other page, i need to check if there is a value "APPROVED" and then display a particular component.

Comment: @user2598808, then you can pass APPROVED as query string and check whether it is passed or not..

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the query string parameters as the other answer say. They are not reliable and it's an open gate for any little hacky joker.

You *could* use the [HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), that you can retrieve with `Request.UrlReferer` (C#) or `document.referer` (js), but they aren't always provided by the browser and aren't really reliable.

In the end, **the only sane and reliable tracking you can do is server-side**. I see two possibilities here :

#### Session tracking (cheap and dirty)

This solution use server-side session. The client gives only the identifier and don't control th content of the session. You can trust this variables.
Here are the steps:

1. When serving the Page1, use `Session['page1_served'] = true`
2. When serving the Page2, check the `Session['page1_served']` variable
3. For any other page, set `Session['page1_served'] = false`

#### Server redirection (more elegant)

This solution use a proxy-link, only provided from your specific case. Wire it to a new action of your controller which *always* render with the special components.

In Page1, change your link to the new action, and you're done.